# Replacing values in a column values with another column (country codes)

Tags: r, country-codes

I have two datasets, baci_2002 and country_codes. Baci_2002 has country codes in 1 to 3 digit numbers and I want to change them to country codes with 3 letters. The dataset country_codes is a table that has the different transformations of different country codes and it looks like this:
[image]

Baci_2002 looks like this:

[image]

Columns "I" and "j" in Baci_2002 are countries with a 1 to 3 number code and I want to transform those codes to the format of iso_3digit_alpha of country_codes. So there must be a comparison in country_codes between columns country_code and iso_3digit_alpha.

I know that there is a package country codes for this kid of operation but it doesn't work for my R version.

Comment: Where did "baci_2002" come from? Is it some other kind of standard for country codes?

Answer (score 1):

You want to execute a `join` of two data sets. Assuming you want to keep the baci data intact and only get the 3 letter alpha codes we'll do a `left_join()` by matching the values in one column of data (`i` in baci_2002) to a column in another (`country_code` in `country_codes`).

```
require(tidyverse)
newData <- left_join(baci_2002, country_codes, by=c('i'='country_code'))
```

You'll get a lot of columns, keep whichever you like.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of the R pkg `countrycode` [depends on R (>= 2.10) and has zero other dependencies](https://cran.r-project.org/package=countrycode)... I find it very improbable that it does not work with the version of R that you are using. You must have an exceptionally rare setup.

If you have a lookup table for the numeric country code, you can do this in base R like this...

```r
country_codes <- data.frame(
  country_code = c(4, 12, 20, 36),
  iso_3digit_alpha = c("AFG", "DZA", "AND", "AUS")
)

baci_2002 <- data.frame(
  t = rep(2002, 12),
  i = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  j = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 20, 20, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36)
)


baci_2002$i_iso3c <- 
  country_codes$iso_3digit_alpha[match(baci_2002$i, country_codes$country_code)]

baci_2002$j_iso3c <- 
  country_codes$iso_3digit_alpha[match(baci_2002$j, country_codes$country_code)]

baci_2002
#>       t i  j i_iso3c j_iso3c
#> 1  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 2  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 3  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 4  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 5  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 6  2002 4 20     AFG     AND
#> 7  2002 4 20     AFG     AND
#> 8  2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
#> 9  2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
#> 10 2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
#> 11 2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
#> 12 2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
```

If you figure out how to get `countrycode` installed, you could do it like this...

```r
country_codes <- data.frame(
  country_code = c(4, 12, 20, 36),
  iso_3digit_alpha = c("AFG", "DZA", "AND", "AUS")
)

baci_2002 <- data.frame(
  t = rep(2002, 12),
  i = c(4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4),
  j = c(12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 20, 20, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36)
)

library(countrycode)

baci_2002$i_iso3c <- countrycode(baci_2002$i, "iso3n", "iso3c")

baci_2002$j_iso3c <- countrycode(baci_2002$j, "iso3n", "iso3c")

baci_2002
#>       t i  j i_iso3c j_iso3c
#> 1  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 2  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 3  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 4  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 5  2002 4 12     AFG     DZA
#> 6  2002 4 20     AFG     AND
#> 7  2002 4 20     AFG     AND
#> 8  2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
#> 9  2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
#> 10 2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
#> 11 2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
#> 12 2002 4 36     AFG     AUS
```

FYI: since it's pretty obvious that you're using CEPII's BACI data, the 3 digit country codes in the BACI data are said to be "ISO 3-digit numeric codes", but they are in fact a custom superset of ISO 3166-1 numeric, i.e. they include about 15 codes/numbers that are not part of the official ISO 3166-1 numeric country code system.